# React app getting stuck for interaction in dev mode after hot refresh

Tags: reactjs

I have a React project which is configured to run using craco. During development, whenever I make some changes, the react app running on browser gets refreshed to render the new changes but I am not able to interact with the application using mouse or keyboard until I refresh the whole page. It's heavily annoying to refresh the app every time after a new save to interact and it completely spoils the advantage of **Hot refresh** feature of React. I joined the project in between so I am not sure what configuration causes this. Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing a lot of research, I found the solution.
The workaround is to add the below to your package.json

If you're using npm

```
  "overrides" : {
   "react-error-overlay": "6.0.9"
}
```

If you are using yarn

```
"resolutions" : {
   "react-error-overlay": "6.0.9"
}
```

After doing this, do install the packages once again and re-start the app. This should help

It is also mentioned in [https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/11773](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/12764)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32889239)

Answer (score 0):

There was an issue - https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/9904

A workaround is putting the below code in index.js to enable reloading

```
if (module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept();
}
```

you must restart your server after making this change

Comment: The page is refreshed and the new changes are also reflected in the app. But I cannot make any interactions like clicking a button, edit text boxes, hover on an item etc. until I manually refresh the page